# Expectation of the product of a Log-normal and an Indicator Function

Tags: probability

I'm trying to show that $$E\left[ e^{\mu+\sigma Z} \mathbf{1}_{\{Z>-d\}} \right] = e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}} \Phi(d+\sigma),$$ where $Z$ is the standard normal.

As standard results I have $$E\left[e^{\mu+\sigma Z}\right] = e^{\mu + \sigma^2/2}$$ and $$E\left[ \mathbf{1}_{\{Z>-d\}} \right] = \Phi(d).$$

Then I take the product (since they're independent) to get something that's almost the required result, but I'm not sure why it should be $\Phi(\sigma+d)$ rather than just $\Phi(d)$.

Comment: You should not take the product; it is wrong because they are not independent. On the other hand, writing the expectation and using the definition will give you your results trivially.

Comment: Why not the direct approach? By *definition* of the distribution of $Z$, $E(e^{\sigma Z};Z>-d)$ is $$\int_{-d}^{\infty} e^{\sigma z}e^{-z^2/2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=\int_{-d}^{\infty} e^{\sigma^2/2}e^{-(z-\sigma)^2/2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=e^{\sigma^2/2}\int_{-d-\sigma}^{\infty} e^{-z^2/2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=e^{\sigma^2/2}\Phi(d+\sigma)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite $E\left[ e^{\mu+\sigma Z} \mathbf{1}_{\{Z>-d\}} \right] = e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}} \Phi(d+\sigma)$ as

$$E\left[ e^{\mu+\sigma Z} \mathbf{1}_{\{Z>-d\}} \right] = Pr(Z>-d)E\left[ e^{\mu+\sigma Z} | Z >-d \right] + Pr(Z<-d)E\left[0\right] = Pr(Z>-d)E\left[ e^{\mu+\sigma Z}  | Z >-d\right] $$

Let $X = e^{\mu+\sigma Z}$ be the log-normal variable. Then, the previous expression can be rewritten as

$$E\left[ e^{\mu+\sigma Z} \mathbf{1}_{\{Z>-d\}} \right]  = Pr(X>e^{\mu - \sigma d})E\left[ X  | X>e^{\mu - \sigma d} \right],$$

which is the partial expectation of a lognormal variable with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. Log-normal partial expectations have a closed-form solution as

$$g(k) = \int_k^\infty \!x{\ln\mathcal{N}}(x)\, dx
            = e^{\mu+\tfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2}\, \Phi\!\left(\frac{\mu+\sigma^2-\ln k}{\sigma}\right)$$

In our problem, $k= e^{\mu - \sigma d}$, so

$$E\left[ e^{\mu+\sigma Z} \mathbf{1}_{\{Z>-d\}} \right] = e^{\mu+\tfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2}\, \Phi\!\left(\frac{\mu+\sigma^2-\ln k}{\sigma}\right)=e^{\mu+\tfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2}\, \Phi\!\left(d + \sigma\right)$$

Comment: So many twists and turns that you lost me. But what is $\mathcal N(x)$ supposed to mean?