# Prove that $\mathbb{E}[e^{\mu+\sigma Z}\mathbb{I}_{\{Z > -d\}}]=e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}Φ(d+\sigma)$

Tags: probability, density-function

[image]

My solution attempt for part (C)

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{\mu+\sigma Z}I_{Z>−d}]= \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{\mu+\sigma Z}I_{Z>−d} \, dx= \int^{+\infty}_{-d} e^{\mu+\sigma Z} \, dx$$ since $$\int^{-d}_{-\infty} e^{\mu+\sigma Z} *0=0$$

So I am left to integrate $$\int^{+\infty}_{-d} e^{\mu+\sigma Z} \, dx=e^\mu\int^{+\infty}_{-d} e^{\sigma Z} \, dx$$ which I don't know how to do since $Z$ is a r.v.

Comment: It is incorrect to replace $I_{\{Z > -d\}}$ by $\phi(x)$.

Comment: Nice latex :-) .

Comment: I tried typing it up, but I couldn't find the characteristic function

Comment: Something to emphasize here: when you convert an expectation of a continuous variable into an integral, all instances of the variable itself in the expectation become $x$. So for instance $E[e^X]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^x f(x) dx$, where $f$ is the PDF of $X$. $X$ itself is no longer anywhere to be found.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1501650/

Comment: Thank you, I feel bad that the solution has been posted already. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of expectation, 
\begin{align*}
& E[e^{\mu + \sigma Z}I_{Z > -d}] \\
= & \int_{-d}^\infty \exp(\mu + \sigma z) \phi(z) d z \\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-d}^\infty \exp\left(\mu + \sigma z - \frac{1}{2}z^2\right) d z \\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)\int_{-d}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(z - \sigma)^2\right) d z \\
= & \exp\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right) P\left(X > -d\right) \\
= & \exp\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)(1 - \Phi(-d - \sigma)) \\
= & e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2} \Phi(d + \sigma),
\end{align*}
where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\sigma, 1)$, in view of its pdf appeared as integrand.